# what is the recommended maximum RAM & DISK size per elasticsearch node?

Tags: elasticsearch

Please, help I was requested to build elk cluster for estimated 100TB monthly logs , so I was wondering what is the maximum possible  memory and storage  size per elasticsearch  node part of log analysis cluster , I heard there is some limits due to java heap memory settings ?

1. 30 fields in different type of logs
2. Analyzer - not very sure here
3. 500 users
4. As faster as possible
5. It possible to keep for 1 year, but 1 month is acceptable
6. At least 3 replicas
7. 1×week Recent data will be searched more
8. Budget -> for hardware almost unlimited, for es licenses -> no
9. Yes all is SSD
10. on premise

Comment: for maximum performance you should have less data in every node. (6 TB disk , 64G ram and 20 core CPU per node). the watermark of disk 85%. so you need 60 server per month. and 720 server per year. try to build a new cluster every two or three month. that is not recommended to have too many server in one cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on:

1. how many field do you want to be searchable?
2. what kind of analyzer do you want to use on every field?
3. how many user/search per minute do you have?
4. what response time will satisfy your users?
5. how long do you want to keep the data?
6. what is the replication factor?
7. will you have more search on newer data? (hot and cold solution)
8. what is your budget?
9. can you afford SSD drive?
10. cloud or on-premise?

so you cannot simply estimate hardware required only base on size of data input.

the best approach is to build a tiny cluster in lab and index some data and estimate final requirement base on your experiment and your boss/users requirement.

> I heard there is some limits due to java heap memory settings ?

yes running JVM using more than 30.5G heap is not recommended. because it is waste of RAM and will reduce the performance and make node more unstable but in some implementation that you dont care about performance and stability and have 512G RAM and 72 TB disk, you could use upper 32G heap (it depends).

Comment: added the answers to the question, but this is mainly what I need to understsnd, what is considered big node and what small node? do I need to create 1000 nodes or 10 will be enought and if more then 64GB RAM is claimed to be unusable and unstable that mean this is the max size that I need to use?

Comment: @R2D2 this is a trade off budget and performance. small nodes cluster are more expensive and need more maintenance and could response to more query at a time.

Comment: Mind elaborating how more than 32g would make the node "unstable"? It's true that because of pointer compression, there's no benefit  in going slightly above 30 gigs, but given enough memory, it becomes irrelevant. You can run nodes with 64 gigs (which happens to be the max for a single RVU of Elastic when licensing) just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @hamid and he gave a very exhaustive list of factors which affects the sizing of ES cluster, but as I can see you have huge amount of data ~100TB monthly, my two cents is that instead of single big ES cluster with **many big size nodes, which might cross the recommended limit of ~31**, instead of this you can create multiple small size ES cluster or if its too much overhead add many small size nodes in your single ES cluster rather than adding small number of big nodes in your single ES cluster. this would provide you better performance with less cost, as ES is heavily depended on heap size and file system cache and having a large amount of data makes caching difficult, which in turn reduces the ES performance.